# express the union and intersections of the circles

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to express  the union  and intersections of the circles $ \ x^2+(y+1)^2=9$ and $x^2+(y-1)^2=9 \ $ in terms of **set comprehension notation.**

**Answer:**

Let ,

$ A=\{(x,y): \ x^2+(y+1)^2=9 \} \ \ and \ \ B=\{(x,y): \ x^2+(y-1)^2=9 \} \ $

Thus,

$A \cup B \ =\{(x,y): x=\pm \sqrt{9-(y+1)^2} \ \cup \ x=\pm \sqrt{9-(y-1)^2} \} $

**Am I right ?**

**If there is more suitable way ?**

Comment: well, the intersection will be two points (-\sqrt{8},0) and (\sqrt{8},0)

Comment: @Vasya Neither the point $(-3, 0)$ nor the point $(3,0)$ is on **either** of the two circles.

Comment: right, it will be $(-\sqrt{8},0)$ and $(\sqrt{8},0)$

Answer (score 2):

$x=\pm \sqrt{9-(y+1)^2} \ \cup \ x=\pm \sqrt{9-(y-1)^2}$

is meaningless, because the $\cup$ operator is an operator on **sets**, not equations. If anything, it should say

$x=\pm \sqrt{9-(y+1)^2} \ \lor \ x=\pm \sqrt{9-(y-1)^2}$

since $\lor$ is the symbol for "or".

---

Other than that, I see no easy way to describe the set, except maybe just lose the square roots and $\pm$ by writing

$$A\cup B=\{(x,y): x^2+(y+1)^2=9\lor x^2+(y-1)^2=9\}$$

or, shorter, but less informative:

$$A\cup B = \{(x,y): x^2+(y\pm 1)^2=9\}$$

Comment: How can I write  the intersection ?

Comment: @mabmath By replacing $\lor$ with $\land$. However, the intersection is just two points, so you can just calculate the two points.

Comment: can not we do it explicitly ?

Comment: @mabmath Yes, you can. That's why I said "you can just calculate the two points".